# Google Maps animate camera doesn't center on location specified

Tags: android, google-maps

I am having a very curious issue and i couldn't find the answers anywhere.

**Goal:**
When i load a model onto a map i extract a point from that model and that point is what i want to set as the new center of camera.

**The problem:**
When i use `map.animateCamera(position)` the camera moves below the model. I cannot deduce what is wrong and I've searched through the documentation but didn't find anything.

**How i tested:**
To test out if the location was correct, i placed a marker on the map where the point is, and that marker is in the correct place, that means that camera is the problem.

I've tried also with different methods `map.moveCamera()` as well as `CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition()`, etc...

**Code**

```
private void recenterModel(List<PolygonOptions> t) {
    if(t == null || t.isEmpty()) return;
    int center = t.size()/2;
    PolygonOptions polygon = t.get(center);
    while(polygon.getPoints().isEmpty()){
        polygon = t.get((++center%t.size()));
        if(center > t.size()+1) return; /*If we are here, there aren't any points in model*/
    }
    center = polygon.getPoints().size()/2;
    LatLng centerPoint = polygon.getPoints().get(center);

    GoogleMap map = modelMapDrawable.ctx.getMap();
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(centerPoint , 15));
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(centerPoint)); 
}
```

**What it seems to me**
When i firstly load the app, it loads project's center point correctly. `map.animateCamera()` works like a charm. Every time i do it for the center point it works. **BUT** when i do `map.animateCamera()` to other location, then i cannot get it to work again.
 *So it seems to me like the camera's coordinate system gets moved*

Comment: have you found any solution. In my case it is like it moves the lat long provided to left top corner of the screen. Not sure how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(centerPoint , 15), 2000, new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {

    }
});
```

This will give some time to animate. I think, the problem here, is with the instant execution of the animation being processed.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to answer you yesterday. It doesn't work that way either...